# How do I open the directory of the current open file?

Tags: vim

If I open a file with `vim dir/to/my/file.c` how can I easily open the directory `dir/to/my` in vim's filebrowser?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try `:Ex[plore]`. From `:help Ex`:

> :Explore  will open the
>   local-directory browser on the current
>   file's
>             directory (or on directory [dir] if specified).  The window will
>   be
>             split only if the file has been modified, otherwise the browsing
>             window will take over that window.  Normally the splitting is
>   taken
>             horizontally.

Comment: Make sure you `set nocompatible` on your `.vimrc` or somewhere else. If you open vim in compatible mode (e..g, `vim -u NONE`), even if you set nocompatible later, `netrw` plugin won't be loaded and you won't be able to run `:Ex`. The following setting might be necessary, too: `filetype plugin on`. More details here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29343/why-isnt-netrw-explore-loaded-when-starting-vim-using-vim-u-none.

Answer (score 106):

I personally prefer the:

```
:Sex
```

command.  It does the split window for you, and drops you into the current directory.

```
:Sex dir/to/my
```

works too.

Comment: You can also use `:Vex` to open the directory in a vertical split.

Comment: And it turns out that `Tex` was exactly what I was looking for (rather than `tabe.`)

Comment: Why can I never remember this shortcut

Comment: `:Sex` is short for `:Sexplore` and `:Vex` is short for `:Vexplore` , and so on.

Answer (score 28):

You could use:

```
:e %:h
```

More info on expansions is here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expand()

Comment: I love this! You can run this command repeatedly to keep going up one directory.

Comment: To turn it into a keyboard shortcut binding to F4, add this to your `.vimrc` file: `noremap <F4> :e %h<cr>`

Answer (score 13):

As already mentioned, you can just do ":Explore" and it will open the file explorer for the directory of the current file.

However, if you need to explicitly specify the directory, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> on the :-command line to read the contents of any register in, and the % register is the current filename, including a path if necessary.  So, just do :e <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>%  then backspace over the filename, and press enter.

There are other ways to do it, but this is the method I usually use.

Comment: I know this is way old, but you can also do `:e %`[tab] which will expand % for you.

Answer (score 7):

For opening Windows Explorer showing current file's directory :

```
:!start explorer /select,%:p
```

(Source : http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_Windows_Explorer_showing_directory_of_current_buffer )

Answer (score 3):

```
:e `dirname %`
```

dirname expands to the directory in which current file is.

Answer (score 3):

Just `:E` should do it. Tested on neovim.

Comment: How do we go back to the file after :E?

Comment: Use this command `:Rex`

Comment: Just `Re`, no need for `x`, appears to work to go back and forth between netrw and editing a file.

Answer (score 1):

:e dir/to/my/

:e . opens the directory you initially launched vim from.

Vim browser 'c' sets the working directory.

I'm not sure if there is a way to automatically jump to the directory of the file you are editing.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit with the `pwd` command on unix it will open the current directory you are in.

```
:e `pwd`
```

This will not work like you want it if you did a `cd` while in vim.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to actually get a shell in it you'll need to `:lcd %:p:h` run `:shell` and then [restore the working directory](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/how-do-you-go-back-to-your-to-global-current-directory-after-inheriting-an-lcd) after you've exited

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch a custom terminal emulator in your current directory's buffer, add something like this to your vimrc:

```
" Set Vim's current directory to the opened buffer
set autochdir
nmap <leader>k :silent !kitty &<cr>
```

Replace `kitty` with your favorite terminal emulator.

See also:

- [autochdir](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27autochdir%27)
- [mapleader](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#mapleader)